# MsBuild linking libraries from command prompt

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, static-linking

I am able to build my VS2010 solution using MSBuild from the command prompt. I would like to write a batch file that builds a solution when executed. The only change would be the static library that is linked to the project. I cannot use dynamic libraries here. I tried the following:

msbuild test.sln /p:AdditionalDependencies=test.lib

It resulted in errors because of the library not being linked to the solution. Is there a way to link libraries from the command prompt?

Comment: Need more information. Can you share what errors were seen? Also, a scaled down version of the project file in question would help. As of now the question is far too abstract.